# .NET 7 API Result<T> not working with Swashbuckle.AspNetCore

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-7.0, swashbuckle.aspnetcore

According to [Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/action-return-types?view=aspnetcore-7.0#resultt-type), the `Result<T>` type should remove the need for the `[ProducesResponseType]` attribute. However, with the latest version of .NET 7, `Swashbuckle` (presumably `EndpointsApiExplorer` actually) doesn't pick these up.

```cs
[HttpGet(Name = "GetWeatherForecast")]
public Results<Ok<WeatherForecast[]>, NotFound> Get()
{
    return TypedResults.Ok(Enumerable.Range(1, 5).Select(index => new WeatherForecast
        {
            Date = DateOnly.FromDateTime(DateTime.Now.AddDays(index)),
            TemperatureC = Random.Shared.Next(-20, 55),
            Summary = Summaries[Random.Shared.Next(Summaries.Length)]
        })
        .ToArray());
}
```

produces swagger spec without response (`WeatherForecast` response type or `404` status code documented), while

```cs
[HttpGet(Name = "GetWeatherForecast")]
[ProducesResponseType(typeof(WeatherForecast[]), StatusCodes.Status200OK)]
[ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status404NotFound)]
public IActionResult Get()
{
    return Ok(Enumerable.Range(1, 5).Select(index => new WeatherForecast
        {
            Date = DateOnly.FromDateTime(DateTime.Now.AddDays(index)),
            TemperatureC = Random.Shared.Next(-20, 55),
            Summary = Summaries[Random.Shared.Next(Summaries.Length)]
        })
        .ToArray());
}
```

produces correct swagger spec (with typed responses).

Answer (score 1):

It's a know issue. You can read this GitHub issue to full detail :
[TypedResults metadata are not inferred for API Controllers](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/44988)

In summary, metadata aren't correctly inferred to action that return type HttpResults... and Swashbuckle use this metadata to generate the OpenApi schema.

---

While waiting for a resolution, I do a operation filter to generate OpenApi response from HttpResults type and I wrapped it in a NuGet package :
[Vernou.Swashbuckle.HttpResultsAdapter](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Vernou.Swashbuckle.HttpResultsAdapter)

You can add the package :

```bash
dotnet add package Vernou.Swashbuckle.HttpResultsAdapter
```

So you can register the filter :

```cs
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
...
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen(options =>
{
    ...
    options.OperationFilter<Vernou.Swashbuckle.HttpResultsAdapter.HttpResultsOperationFilter>();
});
```

If you prefer, you can just copy/paste the filter file from the package repository :
[HttpResultsOperationFilter.cs](https://github.com/vernou/Vernou.Swashbuckle.HttpResultsAdapter/blob/main/src/Vernou.Swashbuckle.HttpResultsAdapter/HttpResultsOperationFilter.cs)

Answer (score 0):

I have tried it, we still need code below to do this.

```
[ProducesResponseType(typeof(WeatherForecast), (int)HttpStatusCode.OK)]
[ProducesResponseType((int)HttpStatusCode.NotFound)]
```

My test

```
    [HttpGet(Name = "GetWeatherForecast")]
    [ProducesResponseType(typeof(WeatherForecast), (int)HttpStatusCode.OK)]
    [ProducesResponseType((int)HttpStatusCode.NotFound)]
    public Results<Ok<WeatherForecast[]>, NotFound> Get()
    {
        return TypedResults.Ok(Enumerable.Range(1, 5).Select(index => new WeatherForecast
        {
            Date = DateOnly.FromDateTime(DateTime.Now.AddDays(index)),
            TemperatureC = Random.Shared.Next(-20, 55),
            Summary = Summaries[Random.Shared.Next(Summaries.Length)]
        })
            .ToArray());
    }
```

Your idea is very good. At present, many people want this feature. You can follow this github issue so that you can receive reminders in time.

[Please support Results as return type of controllers #2595](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore/issues/2595)